# Need help with time zone on javascript date

Tags: javascript

thanks to guys that showed me the prperties to build a custome date...I built it...now i just need the timezone at the end:

```
    var months = new Array(13);
           months[0]  = "Jan";
           months[1]  = "Feb";
           months[2]  = "Mar";
           months[3]  = "Apr";
           months[4]  = "May";
           months[5]  = "Jun";
           months[6]  = "Jul";
           months[7]  = "Aug";
           months[8]  = "Sep";
           months[9]  = "Oct";
           months[10] = "Nov";
           months[11] = "Dec";


        var now = new Date();
        var hour        = now.getHours();
        var minute      = now.getMinutes();
        var second      = now.getSeconds();
        var monthnumber = now.getMonth();
        var monthname   = months[monthnumber];
        var monthday    = now.getDate();
        var year        = now.getYear();



        var systemdate = monthday + " " + monthname + " " + year + " " + "@ " + hour  + ":" + minute + ":" + second
```

This gives me:
 5 Aug 2011 @ 11:11:14

I need:
5 Aug 2011 @ 11:11:14 EDT

THANKS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code to get the abbreviated timezone:

```
var timeZoneAbbr = new Date().toString().replace(/^.*\(|\)$/g, "").replace(/[^A-Z]/g, "");
```

I found the replace expression in the code [here](http://attias.myftp.org/attias/index.php/Javascript_get_client_timezone).  Also, [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/G6bfR/) a fiddle for testing.

Answer (score 2):

```
var gmt = -now.getTimezoneOffset()/60;
```

This will give you an offset in hours. Then you can make an array of GMT strings like you did it with **months**

Comment: It's in hours... I added some notes.

Comment: ahh thanks...I thought there was a method somewhere for timezone name possibly....cool...appreciate that

Comment: Check the other answer. It grabs the timezone from DATE object.

Comment: yeah it does...appreciate the replies